# Защита от инъекций

Tags: php, post, безопасность

Есть форма. Передает данные методом POST
В файле куда отправляются данные, такой код:

```
//инклудится файл подключения к БД...... потом
    $name = $_POST[name];
//и потом всяческие проверки на то, что в этой переменной содержится.`
```

Запросы к базе составляются так

```
mysqli_query($bd, "SELECt......")
```

А если пользователь отправит инъекцию, она ведь получается успешно выполнится до проверок? Или я ошибаюсь? Если нет, то как можно предотвратить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [подготовленные запросы](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

> Значения привязанных к запросу переменных сервер экранирует
>   автоматически.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT code, country FROM table WHERE name=?";
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $name);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $code, $country);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
echo "city: $name, code: $code, country: $country";
```